# OBIEE 12c Last Modified is not updated when we unarchive file

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, obiee

I was trying archive and unarchive functionality in OBIEE 12c .But i observer that some of objects get updated both Last modified and last Accessed field( ex Visual Analyzer Projects objects).
but the problem is some other objects like (scorecard ) only high level folder gets updated both the Last modified and Last accessed. but inside scorecard files gets updated only last accesssed But not last modified

last modified is working only for high level objects only